# Does the warmonger penalty go down over time?

Tags: civilization-6

In Civ6, does the warmonger penalty go down over time? I am in a situation where I have to declare a war without Casus Belli to save my religion, and the penalty is -36 which will totally destroy my relations with civs I've already met. Will it at least gradually go down as long as I don't do anything more for a while, or am I suck with this for the next 350 turns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I determined that the answer is yes. Warmonger penalties go down by 1 per turn, obviously assuming you don't do anything else to increase them.

Comment: Do you need to be at peace for it to go down though (like how War Weariness works)?